# Java Add separator to a string

Tags: java

I wanted to add a separator to a string after every few characters.Now the issue is the number of places is not the same i.e. it is not after every N characters
Thus, if the string is "111111222222223333333444444455566"
I want the output to be like "111111.22222222.3.4444444.555.66"

So I am currently using substring as below;

```
//Please ignore the substring lengths shown below...it is just an example
String s = "111111222222223333333444444455566";
String s1 = s.substring(0, 5);
String s2 = s.substring(5, 15);
String s3 = s.substring(15, 20);

String dashedString = s1 + "-" + s2 + "-" + s3;
```

But my question is if there is any better way to achieve the same ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the requirement in your question - it's very unclear what you're asking for here. Aside from the lack of clarity about where the separator should appear, you seem to have `.` as the separator in the body of your question and `-` in the code, and also the `3` characters are all collapsed into a single `3`, but the other characters all remain as they were - what's that about?

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate through the chars of the string and detect when current char sequence of same characters changes.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String input = "11111122222333444";
    String result = "";
    char currentChar = input.charAt(0);

    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        if(currentChar != input.charAt(i)) {
            result += "." + input.charAt(i);
            currentChar = input.charAt(i);
        }else {
            result += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...But sorry for the confusion...the string 111222333 was just an example...it can be anything like 1345446464...the only known thing is that the separator would be like 1st separator after 5 chars, 2nd after 3 chars, 3rd after 6 chars and so on

Comment: @testndtv Sorry, I still don't understand the question. Do you have the fixed set of places where the separator will be? What is the rule to add a separator on some specific place?

Comment: So the rule to add a separator is a pattern after some digits...So the total length would be fixed (44)...and the separators would be like 1st sep after 5 chars, 2nd after 3 chars, 3rd after 6 chars and so on

Thus, there is no pattern to identify where the separator would appear within the string...just that it would be at fixed "positions: in the string itself and the string is also always going to be fixed length (44)...

Answer (score 0):

In case of fixed separator positions you could use `StringBuilder` with [`insert(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-char-) method:

```
String s = "111111222222223333333444444455566";
String dashedString = new StringBuilder(s)
        .insert(6, '-')
        .insert(15, '-')
        .insert(23, '-')
        .insert(31, '-')
        .insert(35, '-')
        .toString();
```

gives you `111111-22222222-3333333-4444444-555-66`

Comment: That's very error prone sugestion. Take a look at the insert calls and the  indices you passing. You should at least insert from the last position so index would have no hidden "logic" behind.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer depends on what better way is. All of three methods listed below got the same parameters and output.

*Parameters:*

```java
String source = "111111222222223333333444444455566";
String delimiter = "-";
int[] delimiterIdx = new int[] { 6, 14, 21, 28, 31 };
```

*Output:*

```
111111-22222222-3333333-4444444-555-66
```

```java
// 1
public static String joinStringJoiner(final String source, final String delimiter,
                                      final int[] delimiterIdx) {
    final StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
    int prev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < delimiterIdx.length; i++) {
        joiner.add(source.subSequence(prev, delimiterIdx[i]));
        prev = delimiterIdx[i];
    }
    joiner.add(source.subSequence(prev, source.length()));
    return joiner.toString();
}

// 2
public static String joinStringBuilder(final String source, final String delimiter,
                                       final int[] delimiterIdx) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < delimiterIdx.length; i++) {
        stringBuilder.insert(delimiterIdx[i] + i, delimiter);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

// 3
public static String joinSubstring(final String source, final String delimiter,
                                   final int[] delimiterIdx) {
    int prev = 0;
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < delimiterIdx.length; i++) {
        result += source.substring(prev, delimiterIdx[i]);
        result += delimiter;
        prev = delimiterIdx[i];
    }
    result += source.substring(prev, source.length());
    return result;
}
```

1. StringJoiner (can be used to join strings making use of a delimiter, prefix, and suffix)
2. StringBuilder @Ruslan answer
3. Substring (string concatenation as you did)

I run [caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper) benchmark tests and got results:

```
Trial Report (1 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=benchmarkStringJoiner, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=899.88, 1st qu.=902.63, median=903.82, mean=903.48, 3rd qu.=904.74, max=905.88
    objects: min=22.07, 1st qu.=22.08, median=22.10, mean=22.11, 3rd qu.=22.14, max=22.17
Trial Report (2 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=benchmarkStringBuilder, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=276.63, 1st qu.=277.60, median=278.83, mean=278.67, 3rd qu.=279.76, max=280.33
    objects: min=4.08, 1st qu.=4.11, median=4.13, mean=4.13, 3rd qu.=4.16, max=4.19
Trial Report (3 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=benchmarkSubstring, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=2569.33, 1st qu.=2574.14, median=2574.48, mean=2574.47, 3rd qu.=2576.24, max=2576.99
    objects: min=56.07, 1st qu.=56.09, median=56.12, mean=56.12, 3rd qu.=56.14, max=56.17
Trial Report (4 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=benchmarkStringBuilder, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=663.96, 1st qu.=689.33, median=727.41, mean=750.09, 3rd qu.=815.34, max=889.49
Trial Report (5 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=benchmarkStringJoiner, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=1391.68, 1st qu.=1428.84, median=1441.44, mean=1450.81, 3rd qu.=1488.55, max=1502.96
Trial Report (6 of 6):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=benchmarkSubstring, vm=default, parameters={}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=1771.43, 1st qu.=3097.61, median=3142.81, mean=3021.71, 3rd qu.=3214.30, max=3354.84
```

So I guess "the better way" in this case is `joinStringBuilder`method (2).